# Python File write works on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: python

I have a python script which I'm moving onto Linux from Windows, but I am having a problem with a small section of code that writes to a text file.

It works fine on windows, but it gives me an error on Linux.

```
try:
    subprocess.Popen('echo "'+ user_id+'|'+str(op.createdTime)+'" >> dataSeen/%s.txt' % group_id, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
except Exception as e:
   print e
```

on Linux it throws this error:

```
/bin/sh: dataSeen/filename.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You are telling bash to append to a file in a directory that does not exist.

Comment: There is very little point in using Python to call your shell to redirect input to a file. Just use `bash` if you want to do shell scripting. Shell commands are not cross platform: Python is. It would be better to open the file in Python and do the append without a call to `subprocess`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the directory you're trying to write that file to exists. If it doesn't, bash won't automatically create the necessary subdirectories.

before you perform the file write, you can make sure the directory exists using `os.mkdir`.

```
import os

if not os.path.exists('./dataSeen'):
    os.mkdir('./dataSeen')
```

Python also has great built-in file writing operations; you don't need to use `subprocess` to write files via the command line. The built-in functions are more robust if you're running your application across both Windows and Linux, as they're built with cross-platform compatibility in mind.

```
with open('dataSeen/filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(my_data)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the type of response I was hoping for.
I'm not great with python and im modifying a script someone else built for me for use in windows. I'm trying to make it cross platform and learn python at the same time lol. I'll give this a try, it looks to be what I need. Thanks again

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped you, you can upvote it and/or mark it as "accepted" with the checkmark. Welcome to StackOverflow, and good luck moving forward with learning Python!

Answer (score 0):

From that error message, it's unclear whether the problem is that the file doesn't exist within the directory, or the directory itself doesn't exist.

The easiest way to solve it is to make sure the file exists before executing that command.

Comment: Thanks for your advice